# How to pass the parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins JOb which is calling the BAT file which contains the call for   `As java -jar testrunscripts/SQLWorkbench/sqlworkbench.jar -url=jdbc:as400:/;"translate binary"=true;naming=sql;libraries=; -driver=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver -username=-password=-driverjar=E:\\\\resources\\lib\\jt400.jar -script='testrunscripts/HISTORYANDNEWDIFF.sql'`

1-Jenkins Integrats the SQLWorkbench which calls the one `sqlscript(HISTORYANDNEWDIFF.sql)`. which needs the dynamic table name required .

```
WbExport -file='E:\\TestingDATABASE\\history_XAXPGRFE.csv' -type=text    -delimiter=',';
select * from %SOURCE%.XAXPGRFE where XPORIG='JAVAPGM'
```

How would pass the parameter to the query from the jenkins pipeline to bat file and then sql script

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but try to call the bat script from your Jenkins job with a key value pair:

`your_bat_script.bat param1=value1`

and then in the bat script call the SQL Workbench /J script (HISTORYANDNEWDIFF.sql) using the -variable flag:

`java -jar testrunscripts/SQLWorkbench/sqlworkbench.jar -url=jdbc:as400:/;"translate binary"=true;naming=sql;libraries=; -driver=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver -username=-password=-driverjar=E:\\resources\lib\jt400.jar -script='testrunscripts/HISTORYANDNEWDIFF.sql -variable %1'`

http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/commandline.html#cmdline-vardef

`%1` will contain `param1=value1`